# Noethers Symmetries for a system in different cases

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem

If the lagrangian is

$$L=\frac{m}{2}\left( \dot x_1^2+ \dot x_2^2\right)−b(x_1−x_2)^2+a( \dot x_1x_2− \dot x_2x_1).$$

What are the Noether symmetries of the system and the corresponding conserved quantities in the two following cases:

1. $a=0$ and $b=1$.
2. $a=1$ and $b=0$.

The markscheme says for 1) $P_1+P_2$ is conserved and for 2) the conserved quantity is $X_1P_2-X_2P_1$ but I dont understand why? Do I need to use the Noether Charge formula and if so, how do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

For each case you have to follow the following algorithm:

1. Identify continuous transformation that leaves the lagrangian invariant, $L'=L$, or quasi-invariant, $L'=L+\epsilon d\sigma(q,t)/dt$. When symmetries are not obvious from the lagrangian, it is worth to start by checking possible symmetries under space translations, time translations and rotations.
2. Write these transformations as infinitesimal ones,
   $$t\rightarrow t+\epsilon f(q,t),\quad q_i\rightarrow q_i+\epsilon g_i(q,t),$$
   where $\epsilon$ is an infinitesimal parameter.
3. Calculate the conserved charge by applying Noether's Theorem,
   $$C=\sum_i\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q_i}\left(\dot q_if-g_i\right)-Lf+\sigma.$$

Comment: can you please direct me to some resources I can look at to further understand this? @Diracology